# Insert 2 different variables into one cURL line

Tags: php, html, variables, curl

I want to take 1 random value of a variable and insert it into cURL command.
Moreover, after adding the value of this random variable, the cURL should run the function with this value, and in the end of the function, I want it to add a different value to the first one so the function will be completed and the there will be a result.

```
$kinds = array(
    "http://fruits.com/select.php?=",
    "http://vegtables.com/select.php?=",
);
$random = array_rand($kinds);

function get_fruits($fruit){    
   //get content
    $ch = curl_init();
    $timeout = 5;  
    curl_setopt($ch,CURLOPT_URL,$kinds[$random].$fruit);
    curl_setopt($ch,CURLOPT_RETURNTRANSFER,1); 
    curl_setopt($ch,CURLOPT_CONNECTTIMEOUT,$timeout);  
    $content = curl_exec($ch); 
    curl_close($ch);
    return $content;
}

$test = get_fruits('apple');
echo $test;
```

The $test is coming up with a null value. blank.
As you can see, it takes random $kinds and then adds him the $fruit value which is given AFTER the function.

I think it's because of the second line of the function :

```
curl_setopt($ch,CURLOPT_URL,$kinds[$random].$fruit);
```

because if I change

```
$kinds[$random].$fruit
```

to

```
'http://fruits.com/select.php?='
```

everything works great.
I mean, when I use the next way:

```
curl_setopt($ch,CURLOPT_URL,'http://fruits.com/select.php?='.$fruit);
```

Everything works perfectlly.

But I don't want to define the 'http://frutis.com', I want to take a random url from the urls which are given in the array_rand function.

I don't know what to do.

Thanks alot.
I'v already tried the following ways:

```
curl_setopt($ch,CURLOPT_URL,"$kinds[$random]".$fruit); 
curl_setopt($ch,CURLOPT_URL,$kinds[$random].$fruit); 

curl_setopt($ch,CURLOPT_URL,$kinds[$random]."/select.php?=".$fruit); //(when I defined the $kinds as the url only without the select.php)
```

Comment: You're not passing `$kinds` and `$random` in your function?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your $kinds and $random variables are defined outside the get_fruits() function, so either use the keyword global on them inside the function, or send them to the function.

```
function get_fruits($fruit){    
    global $kinds, $random;
    ...
}
```

or

```
function get_fruits($fruit, $kinds, $random){
    ...
}
$test = get_fruits('apple', $kinds, $random);
```

Also, you probably only want to send 1 parameter to the function, the url, rather than sending both the array and the index.

Comment: Hey Mex thanks for the comment. I also want to send the 'apple' as a variable because in the future I want to be able to make some variable which contains 'apple' & other values and send them to the function as a variable. I'll try your suggestions now and update.

Comment: Mex it works!! Thanks alot! I didn't know at all about the 'global' option. thanks alot man.